# Want to split the array element in 10 Chunks based on min and max element in a array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose if iam having below array with min,max in the list of elemnet in the below array,it should divide into 10 chunks,

```
Z=array([[10, 20],
   [5, 30],
   [20, 30],
   [15, 40],
   [40, 55]])
```

it should divide 10 chunks,if we take first element of the 
       array[10,20],so array should be divided into bucket list like this 
       :array([[10-11],[11-12][12-13]....[19-20]]

Next time this bucket should be updated, consider next element say 
        [5,30] where min 5 is less than 10 and max 30 is greater 20.Bucket 
        should be update into 10 equal parts again and this needs to 
        repeated.Bucket remains same if above condition not satisfies.

I tried using for loop, not getting the proper result.

Comment: In your buckets, where does 11 belong? [10-11]? Or [11-12]? What happens if `(max-min-1)%10 != 0` ?

Comment: Why do you mention `where min 5 is less than 10 and max 30 is greater 20`? Why is that relevant?

Comment: iam trying in for loop calculating the bucket list,the bucket list needs to be updated,iam giving the hint that it shuld consider that condition

Comment: Can you add output for, at least, `[5, 30]`? as @yatu noticed, it's not very clear why you said that

Comment: for [5,30] it shuld divide into bucket of 10 but should satisfies the previous elemnet min and max,here it satisfies so it divides into 10 buckets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)